# MySQL Join - Table A all Rows should be joined with each rows of Table B

Tags: mysql, join

I want all rows of Table A should be joined with Table B.

**Table A - Calendar**

```
id date
1  2019-08-01
2  2019-08-02
3  2019-08-03
4  2019-08-04
5  2019-08-05
```

**Table B - Employee Attendance**

```
emp_id  attended_date  ispresented
EMP001  2019-08-01     1
EMP001  2019-08-02     1
EMP001  2019-08-03     1
EMP001  2019-08-04     1
EMP002  2019-08-02     1
EMP002  2019-08-03     1
EMP002  2019-08-04     1
EMP002  2019-08-05     1
EMP003  2019-08-01     1
EMP003  2019-08-02     1
EMP003  2019-08-03     1
EMP004  2019-08-03     1
EMP004  2019-08-04     1
EMP004  2019-08-05     1
EMP005  2019-08-01     1
EMP005  2019-08-05     1
```

this is the sample table.
in Table 1 I have generated Range of Dates

in Table 2 - Employee will have attendance records if attended.

So, i want to date even if employee was not turned on.

i have tried left join and all.

```
join happens based on date if exists on both end.
```

i want to add date which is not exist and remain field will be null by default.

Expected row should be:

```
EMPID   DATE          ispresented
EMP001  2019-08-01     1
EMP001  2019-08-02     1
EMP001  2019-08-03     1
EMP001  2019-08-04     1
EMP001  2019-08-05     0
EMP002  2019-08-01     0
EMP002  2019-08-02     1
EMP002  2019-08-03     1
EMP002  2019-08-04     1
EMP002  2019-08-05     1
```

ETC...

Comment: Can you share your SQL query you have tried. Try to keep Table B as Left and Table A as Right else do Right Join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to get the status of each employee for each date, you need to do a `CROSS JOIN` between a list of employees (selected from `Attendance`) and the list of dates (from `Calendar`), and then `LEFT JOIN` that to `Attendance` to get `ispresented` for each combination:

```
SELECT E.emp_id,
       C.date,
       COALESCE(A.ispresented, 0) AS ispresented
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT emp_id
      FROM Attendance) E
CROSS JOIN Calendar C
LEFT JOIN Attendance A ON A.emp_id = E.emp_id AND A.attended_date = C.date
ORDER BY emp_id, date
```

Output:

```
emp_id  date        ispresented
EMP001  2019-08-01  1
EMP001  2019-08-02  1
EMP001  2019-08-03  1
EMP001  2019-08-04  1
EMP001  2019-08-05  0
EMP002  2019-08-01  0
EMP002  2019-08-02  1
EMP002  2019-08-03  1
EMP002  2019-08-04  1
EMP002  2019-08-05  1
EMP003  2019-08-01  1
EMP003  2019-08-02  1
EMP003  2019-08-03  1
EMP003  2019-08-04  0
EMP003  2019-08-05  0
EMP004  2019-08-01  0
EMP004  2019-08-02  0
EMP004  2019-08-03  1
EMP004  2019-08-04  1
EMP004  2019-08-05  1
EMP005  2019-08-01  1
EMP005  2019-08-02  0
EMP005  2019-08-03  0
EMP005  2019-08-04  0
EMP005  2019-08-05  1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Vy31LzHS3bKc8FBBWNhNG/0)

Comment: Thanks @Nick its working as expected if it is simple table. but mine is derived for demonstration i have to kept simplified one. am about to modify based on query .

thanks

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I've been struggling with a very similar scenario for hours, and was about to post a new question when your answer appeared in the "Similar questions" suggestion list, which solves my problem entirely.

Comment: @AMarch really happy to hear that. Just shows every so often the site works exactly like it was meant to! :)